# How To Define A Generic Type Parameter That Is Self Referencing

Tags: c#, generics, generic-type-argument

Consider the following `class/interface` definitions:

```
public abstract class Foo<TFoo> : IFoo
    where TFoo: Foo<TFoo>
{
    public TFoo This => (TFoo)this; 
}

public interface IFoo { }
```

Suppose I also had a method defined where I wanted to pass in a `TFoo<>` into it:

```
public static void Test<T>() where T : IFoo { }
```

Is this possible without defining a class that removes the self-referencing type constraint?

```
public abstract class Foo2 : Foo<Foo2> { }
```

Is there a way to call the `Test` method without the non-self-referencing class?

```
Test<Foo<?>>();// What goes here <?>
Test<Foo2>();  // This works but I don't want to create a Foo2 class..
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether or not you can skip providing the Generic type, i.e:

```cs
Test<Foo<>>
```

then no you can't, because it is inferred at compile time.

Generally, everything concerning generics and type parameters is specified at compile-time and you can't omit to provide the Generic type parameter or provide a default value.

Comment: It's more of is there a way to define the type for the method without getting into Type-ception: Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo<>>>
I'm guessing my current "solution" is the probably the best way?

Comment: Man, in the end you have to provide something for the last `Foo` :) So yes it's the best.